# PyMC DiscreteMetropolis in Discrete Float Grid

Tags: python, pymc

Currently, I am trying to solve a problem from astrophysics which can be simplified as following :

I wanted to fit a linear model (say `y = a + b*x`) to observed data, and I wish to use `PyMC` to characterize posterior of a and b in discrete grid parameter space like in this figure:

[image: parameter_space.png]

I know `PyMC` has `DiscreteMetropolis` class to find posterior in discrete space, but that's in integer space, not in custom discrete space. So I am thinking to define a potential to force PyMC to search in the grid, but not working well...Can anyone help with this? or Anyone has solved a similar problem? Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated :)

Here is my draft code, commented out potential class is my idea to force PyMC to search in the grid:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import pymc

#------------------------------------------------------------
# Generate the data                    
size                = 200
slope_true          = 12.3
y_intercept_true    = 22.4

x                   = np.linspace(0, 1, size)
# y = a + b*x
y_true              = y_intercept_true + slope_true * x

# add noise
y                   = y_true + np.random.normal(scale=.03, size=size)

# Define searching parameter space 
# Note: this is discrete but not in the form of integer
slope_search_space          = np.linspace(1,30,51) 
y_intercept_search_space    = np.linspace(1,30,51)

#------------------------------------------------------------
#Start initializing PyMC

@pymc.stochastic(dtype=int)
def slope(value = 5, t_l=1, t_h=30):
    """The switchpoint for the rate of disaster occurrence."""

    def logp(value, t_l, t_h):
        if value > t_h or value < t_l:
            return -np.inf
        else:
            return -np.log(t_h - t_l + 1)

#@pymc.potential
#def slope_prior(val=slope,t_l=-30, t_h=30):
#    if val not in slope_search_space:
#        return -np.inf
#    return -np.log(t_h - t_l + 1)

#---

@pymc.stochastic(dtype=int)
def y_intercept(value=4, t_l=1, t_h=30):
    """The switchpoint for the rate of disaster occurrence."""

    def logp(value, t_l, t_h):
        if value > t_h or value < t_l:
            return -np.inf
        else:
            return -np.log(t_h - t_l + 1)

#@pymc.potential
#def y_intercept_prior(val=y_intercept,t_l=-30, t_h=30):
#    if val not in y_intercept_search_space:
#        return -np.inf
#    return -np.log(t_h - t_l + 1)


# Define observed data
@pymc.deterministic
def mu(x=x, slope=slope, y_intercept=y_intercept):
    # Linear age-price model
    return y_intercept + slope*x

# Sampling distribution of prices
p = pymc.Poisson('p', mu, value=y, observed=True)

model = dict(slope=slope, y_intercept=y_intercept, mu=mu, p=p)

#-----------------------------------------------------------
# perform the MCMC

M = pymc.MCMC(model)
trace = M.sample(iter=10000,burn=5000)
#Plot
pymc.Matplot.plot(M)

plt.figure()
pymc.Matplot.summary_plot([M.slope,M.y_intercept])
plt.show()
```

Comment: plus one  for lining up the "=" signs.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem a few days ago. And to my surprise, some of my astronomy friends in Facebook group are also interested in this question, so I think it might be useful to post my solution just in case other people are having the same issue. Please note, this solution may not be the best way to tackle this problem, in fact, I believed there's more elegant way. But for now, this is the best I can come up with. Hope this is helpful to some of you.

The way I solve the problem is very straightforward, and I summarized as follow

1> Define slope, y_intercept stochastic variable in continuous form (`PyMC` then will use `Metropolis` to do sampling)

2> Define a function `find_nearest` to map continuous random variable slope, y_intercept to Grid e.g. `Grid_slope=np.array([1,2,3,4,…51])`, `slope=4.678`, then `find_nearest(Grid_slope, slope)` will return 5, as slope value is closest to 5 in the Grid_slope. Similarly to y_intercept variable.

3> When compute the likelihood, this is where I do the trick, I applied the `find_nearest` function to model in likelihood function i.e. to change `model(slope, y_intercept)` to `model(find_nearest(Grid_slope, slope), find_nearest(Grid_y_intercept, y_intercept))`, which will compute likelihood only upon Grid parameter space.

4> The trace returned for slope and y_intercept by `PyMC` may not be strictly Grid value, you can use `find_nearest` function to map trace to Grid value, and then making any statistical inference from it. For my case, I just use the trace straightaway to get statistics, and the result is nice :)

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import pymc

#------------------------------------------------------------
# Generate the data                    
size                = 200
slope_true          = 12.3
y_intercept_true    = 22.4

x                   = np.linspace(0, 1, size)
# y = a + b*x
y_true              = y_intercept_true + slope_true * x

# add noise
y                   = y_true + np.random.normal(scale=.03, size=size)

# Define searching parameter space 
# Note: this is discrete but not in the form of integer
slope_search_space          = np.linspace(1,30,51) 
y_intercept_search_space    = np.linspace(1,30,51)


#------------------------------------------------------------
#Start initializing PyMC
from pymc import Normal, Gamma, deterministic, MCMC, Matplot, Uniform

# Constant priors for parameters
slope       = Uniform('slope', 1, 30)
y_intercept = Uniform('y_intp', 1, 30)

# Precision of normal distribution of y value
tau         = Uniform('tau',0,10000 )

@deterministic
def mu(x=x,slope=slope, y_intercept=y_intercept):
    def find_nearest(array,value):
        """
        This function maps 'value' to the nearest point in 'array'
        """
        idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
        return array[idx]
    # Linear model
    iso = find_nearest(y_intercept_search_space,y_intercept) + find_nearest(slope_search_space,slope)*x
    return iso

# Sampling distribution of y
p = Normal('p', mu, tau, value=y, observed=True)

model = dict(slope=slope, y_intercept=y_intercept,tau=tau, mu=mu, p=p)


#-----------------------------------------------------------
# perform the MCMC

M = pymc.MCMC(model)
trace = M.sample(40000,20000)
#Plot
pymc.Matplot.plot(M)

M.slope.summary()
M.y_intercept.summary()


plt.figure()
pymc.Matplot.summary_plot([M.slope,M.y_intercept])
plt.show()
```